# How do I retrieve an attribute's keys inside a .yaml file using YQ?

Tags: bash, parsing, yaml, yq

I have the following yaml:

```yaml
attr_keys:
  x:
    y: [1, 2, 3]
    z: 7
```

I need to create a bash script that parses the yaml file, creates various combinations of all the keys' values found under `attr_keys.x` and runs a script various times, passing each time, a different combination of parameters.

Now I am having problems parsing the yaml file. When there is only one key under `attr_keys.x` there are no issues, the script works fine. However when there are multiple keys, it breaks.

I am using `yq` to parse the file:

```bash
parameters_keys=$(yq e ".attr_keys.x | keys | .[] " config.yaml)
for parameter_key in "${parameters_keys[@]}"
      do
        echo "Key: $parameter_key"
      done
```

If we were to consider the following yaml:

```yaml
attr_keys:
  x:
    y: [1, 2, 3]
```

The above script prints `Key: y` and this is correct. Following this behaviour, if I were to consider the following yaml file:

```yaml
attr_keys:
  x:
    y: [1, 2, 3]
    z: 7
```

The expected output should be

```bash
Key: y
Key: z
```

However I get:

```bash
Key: y
z
```

Apparently, multiple keys are parsed as a whole string and considered as one big "key". What I need is to handle multiple keys as an array or a list or something similar, any suggestions on how to do so?

**I am using yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.34.1**

I tried chaining the bash command:

```bash
parameters_keys=$(yq e ".attr_keys.x | keys | .[] " config.yaml)
```

to

```bash
parameters_keys=$(yq e ".attr_keys.x | keys " config.yaml)
```

and to

```bash
parameters_keys=$(yq e ".attr_keys.x | keys | [.[]] " config.yaml)
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: Make `parameters_keys` an array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with yq, the issue is with your Bash script. `varname=$(…)` will always be a (possibly multiline) string, regardless of the logic of the producer. Thus, you cannot just transfer the array logic into Bash, you have to create the array yourself from within Bash, e.g. by assuming item boundaries at line breaks. Use parens for that:

```bash
parameters_keys=($(yq e ".attr_keys.x | keys | .[]" config.yaml))
```

However, it's safer to use one of the Bash builtins (e.g. `readarray`) to do that:

```bash
readarray -t parameters_keys < <(yq e ".attr_keys.x | keys | .[]" config.yaml)
```

Comment: Beware the first solution could break, if the YAML has keys with spaces (which is valid per YAML spec.), as it could undergo word-splitting

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with the `yq` command as such, but the way you are storing the output from the command to the shell context. The `$(..)` executes the command provided inside and produces the result to stdout, which is captured by the variable provided. So as such, a multi-line output is stored in the variable `parameters_keys`, as a single multi-line entry, as supposed to multiple words.

Always use "arrays" in bash to store and process mutli-line command output. See [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) Use builtins like `mapfile` or `readarray` to store them into array. e.g. for your case, it could be

```bash
mapfile -t parameters_keys < <(yq '.attr_keys.x | keys | .[]' config.yaml)
```

and then do the iteration over the array as before.

---

Also note that with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), the `e` flag doesn't need to be specified as it has been [made default since v4.18.1](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [yb](https://github.com/t0pd4wn/yb) with the `-K` (only keys) option.

```bash
declare -a keys_array
keys_array=($(./yb -RKf "config.yaml" -k "attr_keys.x"))

for key in "${keys_array[@]}"; do
  echo "key: ${key}"
done
```